# Pass object reference to Angular2 Component to be used in ngModel

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a component with this code inside:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.title" name="title" required/>
</div>
```

I am trying to migrate the whole thing into another component, `input-component`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-component',
    template: `
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" name="title" required/>
        </div>
    `
})
export class InputComponent {
    @Input() value: string;
}
```

So the first example code will be replaced with:

```
<input-component [value]="model.title"></input-component>
```

When `model.title` is changed, the value inside the HTML element is changed, however when I change the contents of the element, `model.title` does not change.

How can I achieve two-way data binding with this setup?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to create an `EventEmitter` to do this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-component',
    template: `
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="onInput($event)" name="title" required/>
        </div>
    `
})
export class InputComponent {
    @Input() value: string;
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();

    public onInput(event: string) {
        this.value = event;
        this.valueChange.emit(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: @PankajParkar it will not work without `EventEmitter`.

Comment: @micronyks parden me, I thought the other way :) Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

Still better way would be,

```
<input-component [(value)]="model.title"></input-component>
```

---

```
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" name="title" 
                       (keyup)="update(value)" required/>      ///<<<### keyup


    export class InputComponent {
        @Input() value: string;
        @Output  valueChange:EventEmitter=new EventEmitter();  ///<<<### added

       update(value){
           this.valueChange.emit(value);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this better (relying on `keyup` rather than `ngModelChange`)?

Comment: Opps ! I didn't see your answer properly. Yours is better and having no problem.